# How to create REST url for action on my page?

Tags: url, rest

I've created a page for example http://sayhello.com and there's a form fe: http://sayhello/com/myform with fields **yourname** and **yourtext** and button **yoursubmit**. How can I create my REST url?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) first and then provide some more details here about what server-side programming language and framework you are using.